# Source code prompts data has been saved but no data appears in table. Using pyCharm and Postgres for development

Tags: python, postgresql, pycharm

I have a source code which saves a set of data/inputs from the web page I developed. The web page prompts that the data has been saved but upon looking to the table, no records has been saved. I'm using pyCharm and Postgres for this development. Hope anyone can help me out.

By the way, I use a stored procedure in saving the set of data to the table which perfectly fine when I execute it through Postgres.

--
I added the source code upon editing my question. Here's all of the source codes related to my question:

```
from DBHelper import DBHelper

class Manufacturer:
    def saveManufacturer(self, request):
        from django.db import connection, transaction
        helper = DBHelper()
        try:
            sql = format("SELECT savemanufacturer('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')" % (request.POST["manuCode"],
                         request.POST["longDesc"],
                         request.POST["shortDesc"],
                         request.POST["manuFlag"],
                         request.POST["activityStat"],
                         request.POST["activityDate"],
                         request.POST["street1"],
                         request.POST["street2"],
                         request.POST["city"],
                         request.POST["contactPerson1"],
                         request.POST["position1"],
                         request.POST["phone1"],
                         request.POST["contactPerson2"],
                         request.POST["position2"],
                         request.POST["phone2"],
                         request.POST["fax"],
                         request.POST["tin"]
            ))

            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(sql)

            result = cursor.fetchall()
        except Exception,e:
            print(e)

        return result[0]
```

------
I added my stored procedure. Hope this helps in finding the problem. I really appreciate the help:

```
        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION savemanufacturer(mancode text, longdesc text, shortdesc text, manuflag text, actstat text, actdate text, st1 text, st2 text, city text, person1 text, position1 text, person2 text, postion2 text, phone1 text, phone2 text, fax text, tin text)
          RETURNS integer AS
        $BODY$
        DECLARE myActDate TIMESTAMP;

        BEGIN
        myActDate := to_timestamp(ActDate,'YYYY-MM-DD');
        INSERT INTO "DEDGE_master_files_tblvendor"("VendorCode",
                               "LongDesc",
                               "ShortDesc",
                               "ManuFlag",
                               "ActivityStat",
                               "ActivityDate",
                               "Street1",
                               "Street2",
                               "City",
                               "ContactPerson1",
                               "Position1",    
                               "Phone1",
                               "ContactPerson2",
                               "Position2",
                               "Phone2",
                               "Fax",
                               "TIN")

        VALUES(ManCode,
               LongDesc,
               ShortDesc,
               ManuFlag,
               ActStat,
               myActDate,
               St1,
               St2,
               City,
               Person1,
               Position1,
               Phone1,
               Person2,
               Postion2,
               Phone2,
               Fax,
               TIN);
        RETURN 1;
        END;
        $BODY$
          LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

-----
and finally here is the javascript which is also related to this problem:

```
        $("#manufacturer-add").click(function(){
            $("#manufacturer-add").fadeOut();
            $("#manufacturer-save").fadeIn();
        });

        $("#manufacturer-save").click(function (){
            var myData = {
                "token":"savemanufacturer",
                "manuCode":$("#ManufacturerCode").val(),
                "longDesc":$("#LongDesc").val(),
                "shortDesc":$("#ShortDesc").val(),
                "manuFlag":$("#ManuFlag").val(),
                "activityStat":$("#ActivityStat").val(),
                "activityDate":$("#ActivityDate").val(),
                "street1":$("#Street1").val(),
                "street2":$("#Street2").val(),
                "city":$("#City").val(),
                "contactPerson1":$("#ContactPerson1").val(),
                "position1":$("#Position1").val(),
                "phone1":$("#Phone1").val(),
                "contactPerson2":$("#ContactPerson2").val(),
                "position2":$("#Position2").val(),
                "phone2":$("#Phone2").val(),
                "fax":$("#Fax").val(),
                "tin":$("#TIN").val()
            }

            var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
            $.ajaxSetup({
                beforeSend: function (xhr, settings){
                    if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                    }
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: "/DEDGE/AJAX/IM/Maintain/Manufacturer",
                type: "POST",
                data: myData,
                success: function (msg){
                    if (msg==1){
                        alert("Successfully saved manufacturer!");
                    } else{
                        alert("Oops! " + msg)
                    }
                }
            })
        })
```

Comment: Some code would be useful to gain some insight into the problem.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. In order for us to find out what is going wrong in your code, we need to see some of that code - otherwise, we would just be guessing. See [How to create Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for a few tips on what to include and what to leave out.

Comment: I'm going to guess that it's neither PyCharm's nor Postgres' fault, but rather a problem in the code you wrote. So, without telling us anything about your code, there's nothing to help you with here.

Comment: There is no `commit` in your code (as far as I can tell)

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm kinda new to this, but at which part do I place commit?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-transactions.html

Comment: I tried the commit but it didn't help, I'm sorry. Would it help if say that I also used python here? Because I saw that I failed to mention about python in question.

Comment: There is no `insert` command in your code. Where is it?

Comment: The insert command is in an stored procedure which works perfectly fine when I execute it on postgre. The thing is, I don't know why the data doesn't actually insert to the table when I use the stored procedure on my source code.

Comment: try to reinstall postgresql...or install standalone postgre if you are using bitnami. it works for me :-) good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using bitnami? Try to reinstall a stand alone postgresql and try to use `commit`